# Is there a space(variable) in android View to store a custom data?

Tags: android, android-view

Is there an unused variable in a View object where I can store a string of my own?

Comment: explain what do you want ? what do you mean by unused variable in View?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use View's setTag(Object obj) method to set tag and getTag() method to retrieve that

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`setTag(int key, Object tag)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) and the corresponding 
[`getTag(int key)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag%28int%29) methods to store multiple objects in a view.